# Find a non repetitive value in a column

Tags: sql

I have a table "**stats**" that consists **3 ids**.

**IDs:** id_seller, id_part and id_proj

From this table, I want to ****return** id_proj** (project), that only buys from **ONE** **id_seller (seller)**.

**IN other words:** The query should find and return value **id_proj** (project) **that IS NOT** buying from anybody exept one seller.

[image]

In my case or in the example below, **J6** is the **only part that is NOT sold to other sellers**. SO, **J6 is buying only from S2**.

[image]

I tried to find solution with subquery with Count function, but could not get the correct return.

The output should be just **J6**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
  select id_proj,
         count(id_seller)
group by id_proj
  having count(id_seller) = 1
```